# How to synchronize python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to synchronize two threads: one appending, another poping from the list:

```
import threading


class Pop(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, alist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.alist = alist
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        self.pop_from_alist(self.alist)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

    def pop_from_alist(self, alist):
        alist.pop(0)


def main():
    alist = [1, 2]
    # Create new thread
    thread = Pop("Pop thread", alist)
    for x in range(2):
        alist.append(alist[-1]+1)
    thread.start()
    print "Exiting Main Thread"
    print alist
main()
```

How can i do this, should I use Lock or use join methods?
Cant find any synchronization tutorial for beginners

Comment: check out [Python Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). Let me know if you need a full answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both threads need to share the same lock. This way they get to know when the other thread has locked it. You need to define the lock in your main thread and pass it to your threads on initialization:

```
# Create a lock
lock = threading.Lock()

# Create new threads
thread1 = Append("Append thread", alist, lock)
thread2 = Pop("Pop thread", alist, lock)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Within the threads you can handle it the way you already did, but skip lock creation:

```
class Append(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, alist, lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.alist = alist
        self.name = name
        self.lock = lock

def append_to_list(self, alist, counter):
    while counter:
        with self.lock:
            alist.append(alist[-1]+1)
            counter -= 1
```

Comment: There is no need to use lock.acquire and release()?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinnikov: The `with` enter/exit sequence acquires the lock at entry, and releases it at exit.  It's a very nice way to do operations while holding the lock, as it guarantees the lock is released even on exception or keyboard interrupt.